# How to continue request after catching error Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

The thing is if I have a 401 error (token expired) I am making a request for the server to refresh the token. It handles all the requests been sent. It refreshes the token but interrupts the previous request. How to continue request after cathing error?

```
  private handleAuthError(err: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<any> {
    if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) {
        this.authService.refreshToken(this.userData.accessToken, this.userData.refreshToken, this.userData.tokenType).subscribe((resp: any) => {
          this.userData.accessToken = resp.access_token;
          
          this.authService.currentUserSubject.next(this.userData);
          const userData: User = new User(resp);
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(this.authService.currentUserSubject));
          localStorage.setItem(`${JWT_TOKEN_KEY}`, JSON.stringify(userData.accessToken));
        })
        return of(err.message);
    }
    return throwError(err);
}
  public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token: string = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`${JWT_TOKEN_KEY}`));
    const isLoggedIn = token;
    const isApiUrl = request.url.startsWith(environment.apiUrl);
    if (isLoggedIn && isApiUrl) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      });
    }
    console.log(request);

    return next.handle(request)
      .pipe(
        catchError((x: any) => this.handleAuthError(x)));
  }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I think this is a case for a higher order function - you make a function that takes a function, and the function it takes is the function that makes the http request. So your HO function calls that function and awaits the result. If it succeeds, it just returns the result. If it fails, you refresh the token and then call the function again

Answer (score 0):

Just make a new request, you can't use the same one since it already ended

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function to catch any request while error occurs and rewind that request again.

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
        map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                return event;
            }
        }),
        catchError(error => {
            if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                if (error.status === 401) {
                    if (request.url !== Constants.AUTH_ENDPOINT) {
                        this.auth.collectFailedRequest(request);
                        return this.auth.refreshAuthToken().pipe(
                            switchMap((data: any) => {
                                if (data && data.access_token && data.refresh_token) {
                                    localStorage.setItem(Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN, JSON.stringify(data.access_token));
                                    localStorage.setItem(Constants.REFRESH_TOKEN, JSON.stringify(data.refresh_token));
                                    this.auth.cachedRequests = this.auth.cachedRequests.clone({
                                        setHeaders: {
                                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                            'Authorization': `Bearer ${data.access_token}`
                                        }
                                    });
                                    return next.handle(this.auth.cachedRequests); // rewinds previously requested http call
                                } else {
                                    toastr.error(error.error.toUpperCase(), error.status);
                                    this.auth.removeAllTokens();
                                    setTimeout(() => {
                                        window.location.reload();
                                    }, 1000);
                                }
                            })
                        );
                    } else {
                        if (request.body.grant_type === 'refresh') {
                            this.auth.removeAllTokens();
                            window.location.reload();
                        } else {
                            console.log('no refresh grant type');
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    return throwError(error);
                }
            }
        })
    );
}
```